# Deployment of an Azure ML Experiment as a Web Service through Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I used Machine learning tutorial: [Create your first data science experiment in Azure Machine Learning Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/create-experiment) to create an `Experiment` and then converted it to a `predictive experiment`. Now I'm trying to deploy it as a Web Service by following this article that was referenced in the above article: [Deploy it as a web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/publish-a-machine-learning-web-service#deploy-it-as-a-web-service). But when I click on `Run` and then on `Deploy Web Service`, I don't see the `Price Plan` dropdown and `Plan Name` input box etc as mentioned in the section `Machine Learning Web Service portal Deploy Experiment Page` of the second article above. After I clicked on Deploy Web Service link in ML studio, I got the page shown below.**Question**: What I may be doing wrong?

Note: You can click on the picture to get a larger view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on what workspace you're in. If you're in the free one then you get the screen that you already get, but if you create a workspace in the Azure portal and use that one, then you will get a screen like below.

[image]

To create a new workspace, in the Azure Portal, create a new "Machine Learning Studio Workspace" and when you go to Azure ML Studio select the new workspace from the top right.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I created the workspace in Azure Portal. But it does not provide ML Studio interface where you can drag/drop controls to create an experiment. How do I achieve that? Initially I had followed the tutorials mentioned in my original post to create an `experiment` and `predictive experiment` using free account of `studio.azureml.net` that  the tutorial referred to.

Comment: You would continue to go to [Azure ML Studio](http://studio.azureml.net) but on the upper right hand corner you can change your workspace to the new one created in the Azure Portal.

Comment: You were correct. After I followed your instructions, it worked (**thank you**). I'm glad you understood my question; else I was not sure if I explained it well enough for others to try to help. The key is that you create the ML studio workspace in Azure Portal first and then go to [Azure ML Studio](https://studio.azureml.net/) to follow the tutorials mentioned in my original post above.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped! :)